# Read php code on string without eval function

Tags: php

I know eval() in php is to evaluate php code inside string. I also was create a simple template class with eval. But, in practice this way is not comfortable. Very hard to maintain. So, here the simple short snippet code as example

```
function render($view,$data)
    {
        extract($data);
        ob_start();
        include SOMEPATH . 'views/' . $view . EXT;
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $result = str_replace('<cihtml name="apa">',file_get_contents( SOMEPATH . '/views/sample.php' ),$result);

        echo eval( '?>' . $result);
    }
```

I can render it. But in some case, there is always problem where eval get error with specific reason.

Now, what I need here is the concept template parser without eval() function. Thanks for your advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the weel? Most people use frameworks for these kind of things.
Look into
http://phalconphp.com/
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html

Comment: I know there are a lot of framework, but what I want is basic concept in making template engine without using eval function.

Comment: PHP originally was intended as a template language (code in html). When eval is the answer you are asking the wrong question. P